# Strange CSS formatting bug

Tags: html, css

I have a strange CSS bug.  Any steer in where I should be looking?

I have a table.  In the first row of the table, I set the height of the row to 40px.

```
table.categories-table tr.categories-table-row1 {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    inline-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
}
```

This seems to show up in the inspector (tho I don't know why it's greyed out).[image]

However, the row looks taller than 40px, and towards the bottom of the inspector, I see this:

[image]

The stranger thing is as I refresh the screen, the height of the row gets smaller and smaller until it gets to 40px.  Then, subsequent refreshes keeps it at 40px.  However, if I close the tab, open a tab and open the page again, the row is taller than 40px.

Any thoughts on where I should look to crack this bug?

Comment: can line-height:40px; ?

Comment: There is no such `inline-height` style.

Comment: Are you sure it's bug? I suppose you have a looong content in this table. What this content should do instead of changing TD size?

Comment: I changed inline-height to line-height, the issue still persists.
The content of the row is just 1 line of text 'Categories (2)'  or 'Categories ({{categories.length}})' since I'm doing angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues your problem is that you select the `<td>` and you focus your css on the `<tr>`.

So when you do:

```
table.categories-table tr.categories-table-row1 td {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    /*inline-height:40px; not valid */
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
}
```

It shouldn't be grayed out. Also your td will have 40px height.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/bc7aJ/

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  It didn't fix the problem, so I guess the problem is somewhere else that's influencing this.  I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `line-height:40px;`.

`inline-height` is not a valid CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such "inline-height" property. Try "line-height".

```
table.categories-table tr.categories-table-row1 td{line-height:40px;}
```